# Gtk gobject.timeout_add() callback get data from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk

I am not skilled in Gtk programming and I am trying to modify some [existing code](https://github.com/jrfonseca/xdot.py/blob/0.6/xdot.py) so that the gobject.timeout_add() callback function can use data from another thread.

The existing code creates a GUI for displaying a DOT graph by periodically reading a file but I want the DOT data to be read from a string that can be obtained from a subscriber defined as follows:

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
rospy.Subscriber('/dot_string', String, self.update_dot_graph)

def update_dot_graph(self, msg)
    self.dot_string = msg.data
```

The rospy.Subscriber runs in its own thread and so it is unclear to me how to get access to self.dot_string when the Gtk.main() function appears to block any other code from running.

The existing GUI code defines the following callback for gobject.timeout_add():

```
def update(self):
    if self.openfilename is not None:
        current_mtime = os.stat(self.openfilename).st_mtime
        if current_mtime != self.last_mtime:
            self.last_mtime = current_mtime
            self.reload()
    return True
```

Here you can see that the DOT code is read from a file if it has changed since the last read and then the GUI window is reloaded.  I would like instead to use the data in self.dot_string from the other thread to be used in this update function.  Alternatively, I would like to trigger the data update and reload() directly in the update_dot_graph() callback that is attached to the other thread.

Please let me know if more details are needed for this to make sense.

Comment: I can tell you that you are diving off at the deep end. You might want to consider reading up on the Python multiprocessing library https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: So why can you not access the data from the other thread? Threads have shared memory so it shouldn't be a problem.